# How do I remove comment nodes?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an XML document with many comment tags I want to uncomment. For example:

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.archive.modules.CrawlMetadata" autowire="byName">
   <!-- <property name="robotsPolicyName" value="obey"/> -->
   <!-- <property name="operator" value=""/> -->
   <!-- <property name="operatorFrom" value=""/> -->
   <!-- <property name="organization" value=""/> -->
   <!-- <property name="audience" value=""/> -->
</bean>
```

I'm using Nokogiri. Is there any way to remove the comments on the nodes, or to locate them, even when as comments, delete and re-create?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to replace the comments with their content, so uncommenting the markup?

That is easily done:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(<<__XML__)
<bean id="metadata" class="org.archive.modules.CrawlMetadata" autowire="byName">
<!-- <property name="robotsPolicyName" value="obey"/> -->
<!-- <property name="operator" value=""/> -->
<!-- <property name="operatorFrom" value=""/> -->
<!-- <property name="organization" value=""/> -->
<!-- <property name="audience" value=""/> -->
</bean>
__XML__

doc.xpath('//comment()').each { |comment| comment.replace(comment.text) }

puts doc.serialize
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bean id="metadata" class="org.archive.modules.CrawlMetadata" autowire="byName">
 <property name="robotsPolicyName" value="obey"/> 
 <property name="operator" value=""/> 
 <property name="operatorFrom" value=""/> 
 <property name="organization" value=""/> 
 <property name="audience" value=""/> 
</bean>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity what `doc.serialize` method do actually ?

Comment: @OMG: It produces the text XML representation of the data. `to_s`, basically.

Comment: Ok.. so is it same `doc.to_xml`?

Comment: @OMG: Yes. `doc.method(:serialize) == doc.method(:to_xml)` is true. `doc.method(:serialize) == doc.method(:to_s)` is false, but I'm not sure of the difference.

Comment: Could you tell what's the CSS equivalent of `'//comment()'`?

Comment: @OMG: I'm pretty sure there isn't one. An XML comment isn't part of HTML syntax. Also CSS is about styling the rendered page and comments don't get rendered.

Comment: `serialize` isn't the same as `to_xml`, `serialize` is called by `to_xml`, which uses the flags defined in `Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::DEFAULT_XML` AKA `33`, i.e. `Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::DEFAULT_XML
=> 33`. `33` is just a set of binary flags meaning "formatted XML".

Comment: @theTinMan: You're looking in the wrong place. Examine `nokogiri/xml/document.rb` and you will see `alias :to_xml :serialize`.